C++ interface with only one implementation without performance overhead (for mocking in unit tests)
I am making a game engine in C++ and want to start implementing unit tests.
As far as I'm aware, you can only create mocks of pure virtual functions.
However, because I do not want to add needless performance overhead to my engine, I don't use interfaces anywhere.
If I were to add interfaces to my codebase, there would only be 1 implementation per interface. Is there a way to remove the overhead of the pure virtual methods in that case?

What do you need to mock in your project? Which module is it, what does it do, why you need to mock it?

You can use static polymorphism (templates) instead, see example in googlemock documentation: https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#MockingNonVirtualMethods. But choosing how to test something has a lot of variables that makes it impossible to give an answer tailored to your needs.
